# The YouTube API stopped allowing 480p playback...?

Tags: youtube-api

Last week I noticed that my videos stopped playing in 480p on my website.
I use a WordPress plugin that allows me to specify playback at this quality level.
It's been working for years but now the player defaults to 360p.

Does anyone know if the Google boys made a change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

YouTube removed the non-DASH streams for 480p and 1080p. This means that you'll no longer be able to watch 480p and 1080p videos in YouTube's HTML5 player if you use Firefox or Safari.

Firefox is working on implementing Media Source Extensions.  They're also working with YouTube to prioritize the parts needed to get YouTube's HTML5 player working with adaptive streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like when the user is LOGGED IN to their google account, then the youtube player is basing the video playback quality on the user's settings. If you set the player to the new "Auto" option, then the playback returns to normal e.g. 480p.

Also, if you LOG OUT of Google, the player returns to normal.

So it appears this is a newly implemented feature in which, when the user's session is active, then all YouTube players will attempt to play video at the active user's assumed preferred quality level.